# Alternative to forking process in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For large cpu-based tasks on my server I'm using:

```
var n = cp.fork('./worker.js');

// tell worker to start work
n.send({"msg": "startWork"});

// worker has finished
n.on('message', function(m) {       
    // continue here..
});
```

I do this because that way my server is free to service other client connections.

However, I'd much rather not split my code up into different files, anyone know a good npm module perhaps a  threading library that allows me to do this, i.e., spawn a worker function on a new thread and then get a callback when it's done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [webworker threads](https://www.npmjs.org/package/webworker-threads), it should do what you're looking for.  Also consider writing CPU intensive tasks in a more efficient language like C++ and making those tasks asynchronous through the use of [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv), if you have the necessary skillsets to do so, it will be much more efficient.

Edit: Also, don't fear splitting your code up into different files, if done correctly it's a very useful way to organize your code.